# Can SARS-CoV-2 possibly overcome herd immunity without mutation in densely populated countries and places?

Tags: covid-19, immune-system, vaccination, coronavirus, virus

Can the coronavirus that causes covid-19 possibly overcome herd immunity without mutation using immune individuals as hubs till it reaches vulnerable individuals in very densely populated countries and places such as schools, prisons, stadiums and subways etc?
I read that in a research test subjects (monkeys) were had a fever for a short time.
In other words, can immune recovered or vaccinated patients whith good levels of antibodies retransmit the virus in the short period between infection and defeating the virus?

Comment: See my comments on your other questions. You need to do at least some basic research on your own first and show us what you found or what you searched for if you found nothing.